# Converting list of objects to count map using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list of Item objects. ItemCategory is an enum.

```
public class Item {
    private String itemId;
    private String itemName;
    private ItemCategory itemCategory;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

I want to convert this list to a map of `{ItemCategory -> total_quantity}`

For ex.

```
"items":[
        {
            "itemId": "item_1",
            "itemName": "A",
            "itemCategory": "category1",
            "quantity": 50
        },
        {
            "itemId": "item_2",
            "itemName": "B",
            "itemCategory": "category1",
            "quantity": 10
        },
        {
            "itemId": "item_3",
            "itemName": "C",
            "itemCategory": "category2",
            "quantity": 10
        }
    ]
```

This will be converted to map: `{"category1"->60, "category2"->10}`

The simple approach would be to loop over items and create a map.
I was thinking if there's a way to achieve this using streams.

Comment: Yes, using `groupingBy` and `summingInt`. And try it yourself first, don't be lazy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stream for that operation.

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getItemCategory, Collectors.summingInt(Item::getQuantity)))
```